# Computing the Chern classes of $\mathcal{O}_C(n)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an algebraic K3 surface and $C \subset X$ a smooth rational curve, with $i \colon C \to X$ the inclusion. Let $f \colon C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be an isomorphism, and let 
$\mathcal{O}_{C}(n)$ be the sheaf defined as 
$i_* f^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(n))$
How does one compute the Chern classes of this sheaf?

Comment: I believe you basically increase the degrees of the Chern classes of the sheaf on the curve by $1$, so that $c_1$ is the class of $C$ in $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$ and $c_2$ is the degree $n$. You can see if this is correct using Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch.

Comment: @TabesBridges I'm still having difficulties, can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Well I was not quite right...in any case, Sasha's answer is quite nice and the proper way to do this (GRR is overkill).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are points on $C$, there are exact sequences
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_C \to \mathcal{O}_C(n) \to \oplus_{i=1}^n \mathcal{O}_{x_i} \to 0
$$
and
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_X(-C) \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_C \to 0.
$$
They give
$$
c(\mathcal{O}_C(n)) = \frac{\prod c(\mathcal{O}_{x_i})}{c(\mathcal{O}_X(-C))} = \frac{(1 - P)^n}{1 - C} = (1 - nP)(1 + C + C^2) = (1 - nP)(1 + C - 2P) = 1 + C - (n + 2)P.
$$